# Can Protobuf .netcf handle serializing/deserializing a static property or parameter?

Tags: parameters, static, protocol-buffers

I have a class with many parameters and was using Protobuf to save and load.  When I changed a few to static, they were not getting loaded.  I am using a runtime model.  Is there a way to handle static parameter and properties?

Answer (score 0):

No. And as far as I know, **no** serializer API supports static members. The point of a serializer is to transfer objects (or values) to / from a data format. Statics don't really fit into that.

Comment: Makes sense.  I created some properties and API to work around it.